# Web service can connect in IE, but can't connect by Visual studio

Tags: web-services, visual-studio, internet-explorer, connection, administration

I have a problem with connection to web service. I start work in new corporation, that and get new computer with firewall etc.

I have a Web Service, that are in internet (with .pfx key). I can connect to that web service by Internet Explorer. I can connect to that web service by Visual Studio wiht internet from  iPlus (mobile internet from pendrive), but when I'm in corporate network I can't connect to that web service.

My colleague can connect to that web service by corporate network, so something is blocking me.

How to check what is blocking me, and what to do, to connect to that web service by corporate network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your corporate environment will block the Web Service.
Can you please try the following?

1. Add the Firewall outbound rule to allow to access the web service
2. Add the web service as trusted URL in your anti-virus (or just pause the protection of anti virus to identify the cause of issue)
3. Add the domain/ip address as trusted in your IE

Comment: I added part 3 by my self and now works, and connect to my proxy server (after instalation of fiddler, new page of proxy show up).

Answer (score 0):

I also notice something strange. 
When I stoped Visual Studio, make some code and run, I get '407 error'. I start running 'fiddler', make run code again and... start working. Strange.